# Citations in bibliography showing line by line

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the `BibLaTeX` package and the `memoir` document class. I have coded my `\printbibliography` command in the backmatter, but when I view the pdf, it shows each citation line by line. Can someone help me fix this so each citation prints continuously?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,leqno,openbib,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, backref]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\addbibresources{References.bib}
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\begin(document}
In recent years\cite{dorri2018multi}. fields \cite{shamshirband2013appraisal}.
\backmatter
\printbibliography
\end[document}
```

The references are

```
@article{dorri2018multi,
title={Multi-agent systems: A survey},
author={Dorri, Ali and Kanhere, Salil S and Jurdak, Raja},
journal={Ieee Access},
volume={6},
pages={28573--28593},
year={2018},
publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{shamshirband2013appraisal,
title={An appraisal and design of a multi-agent system based cooperative wireless intrusion detection computational intelligence technique},
author={Shamshirband, Shahaboddin and Anuar, Nor Badrul and Kiah, Miss Laiha Mat and Patel, Ahmed},
journal={Engineering Applications of Artificial Intelligence},
volume={26},
number={9},
pages={2105--2127},
year={2013},
publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please Edit your question and add code, we can copy and compile. It should contain: the class, the preamble (packages you need here), reduced code (i.e. showing e.g. 3 citations and just those 3 entries), \end{document} .

Comment: I think you look for bibliography styles. Though you can find them in the huge manual of that package, a better source might be this https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_citation_styles , which links to an overview of common styles: https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_bibliography_styles .

Comment: If this is a `biblatex`-generated bibliography the most likely explanation is that you have `block=par,` or `block=npar,` somewhere. If that is not the case it could be a number of other things (none of which spring to my mind readily). Please show us a small example document that reproduces the output you get with as little code as possible (sometimes called an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). Usually an MWE gives us most information we need and we can test and suggest solutions directly.

Answer (score 1):

The output you are seeing is due to the

```
openbib
```

option you pass to the document class.

Remove this option and you should see a more compact bibliography.